# Skrollr Plugin Mobile vs Desktop

Tags: parallax, skrollr

I was having issues with the skrollr parallax scrolling plugin not allowing me to scroll on mobile, but I found the solution. The solution in the documentation is to add

```
id="skrollr-body"
```

to a wrapper around all non-fixed elements you want to scroll on your page. This fixed the issue on mobile, but now my fixed elements (i.e. the header banner on my page) are not remaining fixed on desktop. They are just scrolling with the rest of the page in my browser now.

I'm wondering if anyone here (maybe  with experience using this plugin) can tell me if I'm not doing this correctly? Or is adding some sort of script where

```
id="skrollr-body"
```

is only appended to the wrapper element when a mobile device is detected the right direction to head in?

Thanks in advance for any help.